# What is position controlled joint ,velocity controlled joint

Tags: ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could someone please explain me the following in one line
joint state,
joint command,
position controlled joint,
velocity controlled joint,
effort controlled joint.

I am reading ros_control and I keep getting these terminology again and again.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213642/what-is-position-controlled-joint-,velocity-controlled-joint/) by [prrraveen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21441/prrraveen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2015-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**joint state** refers to sensor readings like actual position, velocity and effort.

A **position controlled joint** is a joint that can be commanded with joint position references. A similar reasoning applies to velocity- and effort-controlled joints.

A controllable joint typically reports its state (read from joint) and accepts motion commands (write to joint).

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2